# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET Apple/Unix devices on Home Wifi

Tags: macos, google-chrome, internet

I'm having this weird problem of `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` that have been happening for a while, I cant load pages properly or use CURL, WGET to download packages.

This happens on the iPhone, Macbook Pro, Macbook Air and Raspberry Pi.

When I disconnect from my home network and use 4G on the iPhone, and even when I use it as hotspot, the websites open as expected.

If you take a look below this is one of the things that happen on curl, both Raspberry and Macbook have the same issue. (I've also tried to download it manually)

[image]

Here's another image:
[image]

I've tried to disable the Firewall, change the MTU rate, nothing works.
I can't find a pattern on this error because 99% of the websites work as expected.
Have someone experienced this already? And What's the solution for this?

Comment: So what you're saying is that on your home internet service none of your devices are able to access a few specific web pages?

Comment: iOS devices / Macs and my Raspberry PI. My work computer running win 10 and my work phone running android have no problems. If I connect to other network it works fine for all devices. I just dont understand why my WiFi Connection only affect certain devices and not all... Weird right?

Comment: That is not at all what your question seems to be asking though. Please use the EDIT button to more clearly state what is and what is not working and where.